# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+n+2) (n+1)}=\psi^{(1)}(1+z)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Proving that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+n+2) (n+1)}=\psi^{(1)}(1+z)$$

The evaluation of the partial sum by Mathematica suggests the series can be expressed in
terms of the hypergeometric function. Then, when taking the limit to $\infty$, we expect to get
the right side. What elementary *real analysis*-solutions would you propose for proving
this result  (without making use of the hypergeometric function)?

Comment: Might it help to write the gamma functions in terms of a single beta function?: $\frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+n+2)}=\text{B}(n+1,z+1)=\text{B}(n,z+1)\frac{n}{n+z+1}= \text{B} (n,z)\frac{n}{n+z+1}\frac{z}{n+z}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum is
\begin{align}
S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(z+1)}{(n+1) \Gamma(n+z+2)}
\end{align}
and can be evaluated as follows.
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} \ B(n+1, z+1) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} \ \int_{0}^{1} t^{n} \ (1-t)^{z} \ dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^{z} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n}}{n} \right) \ \frac{dt}{t} \\
&= - \int_{0}^{1} t^{-1} \ (1-t)^{z} \ \ln(1-t) \ dt \\
&= - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{z} \ \ln(t)}{1-t} \ dt \\
&= \psi_{1}(z+1).
\end{align}
The last step follows from the derivative of 
\begin{align}
\psi(z+1) = - \gamma + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - t^{z}}{1-t} \ dt 
\end{align}
with respect to $z$.

Comment: A good job! (+1)